# Block diagonalizing a Hamiltonian using a symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, chirality

I have the following Hamiltonian, describing the 3 state Chiral clock model in 1D:
$$H = -f \sum_{j=1}^L (\tau_j^\dagger e^{-i \phi}+h.c.)-J\sum_{j=1}^{L-1}(\sigma_j^\dagger\sigma_{j+1}e^{-i\hat{\phi}}+h.c.)$$
This is essentially a generalization of the Transverse Ising model, where the first term generalizes the flip term and the second generalizes the interaction term. If I restrict my spin values (the $\sigma$s) to take on the values 1, $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, where $\omega = \exp{(i 2 \pi /3)}$, I have a symmetry in that if all the spins are rotated by $\omega$, nothing changes. The operator that effects this symmetry is defined as 
$$\omega^P = \prod_{j=1}^L \tau_j^\dagger$$
It can be seen that 
$$[\omega^P,H]=0$$
And for different values of L, $\omega^P$ always has 3 eigenvalues with multiplicity $3^{L-1}$. This tells me that there should be a way to Block diagonalize $H$ so that, into sectors. such that each sector corresponds to a particular eigenvalue of $\omega^P$. I am lost as to how I can go about doing this. For concreteness, I am currently working with L = 3 and L = 4. How should I implement the block diagonalization? Do I need to first convert my Hamiltonian into non-local form, since $\omega^P$ is itself non-local?

Comment: Each configuration has a fixed value of $/omega^P$ associated with it, like charge, and those configurations with the same value can be organized into the same block. In other words, the Hamiltonian takes configurations with a fixed omega value to configs with the same value.